# Flask not receiving data from ESP-12 (NodeMCU) HTTP POST

Tags: python, post, flask, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to receive data from HTTP POST generated and sent by a NodeMCU (ESP-12) to a Flask server (PC) on the same LAN. The server console shows the incoming POST and the response correctly, but the data on the POST body doesn't exist on server side.

Server IP: 192.168.0.19

ESP-12 IP: 192.168.0.16

POST request sent by ESP-12:

```
POST /newLog HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.19:8002
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

count=5&device=0
```

This is the serial log from the ESP-12 (connection-request-response-disconnection):

```
connecting to 192.168.0.19
Requesting: POST /newLog HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.19:8002
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

count=5&device=0
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 18
Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.6
Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 12:59:24 GMT

ok.. Log received!
closing connection
```

This is the endpoint on Flask server(shows request info):

```
@app.route('/newLog', methods = ['POST'])
def newLog():

if request.method == 'POST':
    app.logger.info("fue un POST")
    app.logger.info(request.form)
    app.logger.info(request.args)
    app.logger.info(request.values)
    app.logger.info(request.data)
    return render_template('ok.html')

return render_template('fail.html')
```

And the log from the server:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:96]:
fue un POST
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:97]:
ImmutableMultiDict([])
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:98]:
ImmutableMultiDict([])
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:99]:
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
 INFO in app [app.py:100]:

-------------------------------------------------------
192.168.0.16 - - [14/Nov/2017 09:59:36] "POST /newLog HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It's look like the request arrived but flask does not find any data.

When i try with Postman the POST is quite similar:

```
POST /newLog HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8002
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 79566598-b1b9-de1b-4bf9-e53d38edb232

count=5&device=0
```

And the server does receive the data:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:96]:
fue un POST
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:97]:
ImmutableMultiDict([('device', u'0'), ('count', u'5')])
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:98]:
ImmutableMultiDict([])
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:99]:
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('device', u'0'), ('count', u'5')])])
---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [app.py:100]:

---------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2017 10:31:07] "POST /newLog HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Please help!

Comment: **args:** A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark).I am not sure but when you send request to flask server maybe your url doesnt look like this `/newLog/count=5&device=0` but when you try with `postman` It creates a url like this. You have to make sure your url look like that I showed for `query string`.

Comment: I don't want to send the data in the URL with the `query string` like in HTTP-GET. I want to send it in the body like a form in HTTP-POST does.